# "grails -Dserver.port=9999 run-app" not effective

Tags: grails

I want to use port `9999` to launch the grails server:

```
grails -Dserver.port=9999 run-app
```

however, it doesn't work. The console show an error:

```
Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler["http-nio-8080"]
   java.net.BindException:Address already in use:bind
...
```

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: The version is  3.0.1 and I run in windows7

Comment: yes, add the  server: <br>port: 9999    in file application.yml do changed the default port.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Launch grails with `-Dgrails.server.port.http=9999` on the command line. And set the GRAILS_OPTS environment variable to `-Dgrails.server.port.http=9999`

Comment: have tried it. still not work. The same errors show